# how to compare in IF condition in Procedure

Tags: mysql

i'hve created procedure which works fine but it never get inside the if block. in if, i compare leave_Type with 'Cl'.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`satish`@`%` PROCEDURE `p_Leave_Approval`(
IN uname varchar(45),
IN coment varchar(200),
IN approval varchar(1)
)
BEGIN

-- declare str varchar(2);
-- set str = 'CL';
SELECT Emp_ID INTO @empid 
FROM employee 
WHERE Emp_F_Name=uname; 

UPDATE staff_leave_detail 
SET Leave_Comment=coment
    ,Leave_Status=approval 
WHERE Emp_ID=@empid 
      AND Leave_Status='P';

SELECT Leave_Start_Date, Leave_End_Date INTO @sd, @ed 
FROM   staff_leave_detail 
WHERE  Emp_ID=@empid AND Leave_Status='P';

SELECT DATEDIFF(@sd,@ed)  AS 'd2 - d1' INTO @s;
SELECT Leave_Type INTO @lt 
FROM   staff_leave_detail 
WHERE  Emp_ID=@empid 
       AND  Leave_Status='P';

IF @lt = 'CL' THEN

   UPDATE staff_leave 
   SET AP_CL = AP_CL - @s , 
       AV_CL = AV_CL + @S 
   WHERE Emp_ID = @empid ;

END IF;
END
```

Comment: You are not declaring `@lt` or anything else.... are you sure `@lt` is a string? Please declare your variables.

Comment: Are you sure that the `SELECT` that's meant to set `@lt` is returning a row?

Comment: @lt stores the values Leave_Type of staff_leave_detail. and work fine if i execute as simple query:

Comment: Damien -> i hope when i execute it alone :                          Select Leave_Type into @lt from sims.staff_leave_detail where Emp_ID=4 AND Leave_Status='P';
 select @lt;    then it display @lt=CL

Comment: The problem might be the calculation of @s .... even if the IF is executed properly, if @s - for any reason - is 0 you won't see any change to AP_CL, AV_CL

Comment: @s i fine i just cheked it

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to compare strings in

```
IF @lt = 'CL' THEN
```

Then shouldn't you be using string comparison function?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html